# How to generate PDF Document into bytes data (or binary) in memory without creating (or saving) file?

Tags: pdfclown

I'm new to PDF Clown and, taking a look at the samples included in its distribution, I noticed they use `file = new org.pdfclown.files.File(path)` to create new PDF files, then `file.Save(anotherPath)` to save them to the file system, but I couldn't find any example that would allow me to *generate PDF documents and save them into byte array to be stored in RAM memory*.

Basically what we're doing is to pass our customer's input data to the PDF document, generate it in memory, then attach it to emails or save it to database, without needing intermediate disk storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right way to save a file to a memory stream (C#):

```
org.pdfclown.files.file = . . .;
. . .
var targetStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
file.Save(new org.pdfclown.bytes.Stream(targetStream), SerializationModeEnum.Standard);
```

In the next few days I will commit to the project's [repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/) (version 0.1.2.1 or later) a simplified overload, so you could just do this:

```
var targetStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
file.Save(targetStream, SerializationModeEnum.Standard);
```

Why have we used the `org.pdfclown.bytes.Stream` wrapper in the former `Save` method? Because, as PDF Clown is implemented in multiple platforms (Java, .NET), it needed an abstract common interface to consistently deal with I/O and simplify code development and maintenance across those platforms.

PS: If you are interested to the latest news about PDF Clown, don't miss to subscribe [its twitter stream](https://twitter.com/pdfclown)!

Comment: Got it working now.  I did find this `pdfclown.org/` website which then direct me to download the zipped file from `sourceforge.net` website.  Assuming it's the latest download file, when I unzipped it - I found those samples citing the use of `Serialize` in this unzipped folder `PDFClown-0.1.2-Beta\PDFClown\dotNET\pdfclown.samples.cli\src\org\pdfclown\samples\cli` .

Do you know where I can find a more up-to-date documentation on using PDFClown, as well as a more up-to-date sample features/scripts.  Or is what I found in zipped file & on PDFClown.org the only one at this time?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you plan to keep the PDFClown DLL up-to-date on NuGet?  What I found there is version 1.2 only.  Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I got it: you were referring to Sample.Serialize method, *not* File.Serialize (which actually was superseded by File.Save), excuse me! ;-) 
Anyway, http://www.pdfclown.org is the *official website* of the project and the version you downloaded (0.1.2) is the current one, so you are OK.

Comment: I have planned to maintain official NuGet and Maven packages by the next release (0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks man!  :-)  Reason we use NuGet is cuz of Website & Application source codes being placed on TFS (Team Foundation Service) when using Visual Studio, so other developers within my company can use it.  Multiple developers here.  :-)